# Different output with php client and with a browser

Tags: php, pipe

Maybe my question is simple, but I'm not able to answer it.

I have this little php code:

```
<?php

$line="echo 'hello' | lpr -Pmyprinter";
$out=system($line,$output);
?>
```

When I execute this code using my command line (I use linux with php 5.3.6 and apache 2.2.17) it's printed 'hello' in myprinter.

If I execute this code using my browser it looks like the pipe is ignored!

I have tried with exec(), passthru(), etc. and results are the same.

Thanks for your help.

P.S: I ran previously this code with PHP 5.1.¿¿??

Comment: Do the web server user have permission to use the printer?

Comment: try to run your script as apache-user (www-data on debian) from the terminal

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes, I executed the script from the terminal as apache user (is apache in my system) and it works ok. Also, I used the php command get_current_user() to be sure that the script is executed as apache. The user is the same but with the web server it doesn't run.

Comment: try to put the code in a shell script and run that script from php. also, your apache environment has much less environment variables which might influence the behavior.

Comment: By the moment I am able to rewrite the above code as: $line="echo 'hello' > /tmp/file ; lpr -Pmyprinter /tmp/file"; In this way I can execute it with the same result from the terminal or from the browser. Anyway my doubdt is why is the pipe ignored whe I execute the script using the browser? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
echo `echo hello | lpr -Pmyprinter`
```

Comment: Hi. I have just tried it and the result is the same, using php with terminal it's ok and from the web browser pipe is ignored.

Comment: What about using escapeshellarg and/or escapeshellcmd?